# Short horizontal line at the bottom of the first page using \documentclass{article}

Tags: article, amsart

Usually, when one uses `\documentclass{amsart}`, a short horizontal line appears on the first page in the lower left hand corner. If one includes information such as keywords and MSC, this information usually appears below that line.

Is there a way to make LaTeX draw this line automatically when using `\documentclass{article}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the necessary additions to `article` in order to duplicate the look of the *footnote* in [`amsart`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsart):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\def\@addpunct#1{%
  \relax\ifhmode
    \ifnum\spacefactor>\@m \else#1\fi
  \fi}
\newcommand{\keywordsname}{Key words and phrases}
\def\@setkeywords{%
  {\itshape \keywordsname.}\enspace \@keywords\@addpunct.}
\def\keywords#1{\def\@keywords{#1}}
\let\@keywords=\@empty
\g@addto@macro{\maketitle}{\begingroup%
  \let\@makefnmark\relax  \let\@thefnmark\relax%
  \ifx\@keywords\@mpty\else\@footnotetext{\@setkeywords}\fi%
  \endgroup}
\makeatletter

\title{My title}
\author{My author}
\keywords{some, keywords, for, this, article}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}
\section{introduction}\lipsum[2-4]
\end{document}
```